# Unix Cached Memory

Tags: unix, cache

We have a problem where the cached memory is filling up rapidly on our system.
We are not sure why this is filling up so quickly and would like to understand why

Is there any script/commands available that allows you to view the contents of the unix cached memory?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> We have a problem where the cached memory is filling up rapidly on our system.

In Unix view, unused memory is a problem. Hence a good Unix system tries to utilize memory as much as possible, like, for example, using it as cache.

> Is there any script/commands available that allows you to view the contents of the unix cached memory?

Not as far as I am aware.

You can try using [atop](http://www.atoptool.nl/) to see if there is a process writing too much data clogging the system.

Comment: thanks Maxim. The problem we have is that the cached memory is filling up and causing us to run out of memory

Comment: @Damo: This shouldn't be caused by caching in the kernel. It can be some other application using too much memory or writing to disk too much, so that the disks can't keep up.